# Express.js Csurf working in postman but not React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to setup CSRF tokens so that I can do a number of checks before issueing a token to the client to use in future requests.

Taking the guidance from the csurf [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#value), I've setup my express route with the following:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
const csurf = require('csurf');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

const ErrorClass = require('../classes/ErrorClass');

const csrfMiddleware = csurf({
    cookie: true
});

router.get('/getCsrfToken', csrfMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // code for origin checks removed for example
        return res.json({'csrfToken': req.csrfToken()});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return await ErrorClass.handleAsyncError(req, res, error);
    }
});

router.post('/', [csrfMiddleware, parseForm], async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // this returns err.code === 'EBADCSRFTOKEN' when sending in React.js but not Postman
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return await ErrorClass.handleAsyncError(req, res, error);
    }
});
```

For context, the React.js code is as follows, `makePostRequest` 100% sends the `_csrf` token back to express in `req.body._csrf`

```
  try {
            const { data } = await makePostRequest(
                CONTACT,
                {
                    email: values.email_address,
                    name: values.full_name,
                    message: values.message,
                    _csrf: csrfToken,
                },
                { websiteId }
            );

        } catch (error) {
            handleError(error);
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }
```

Postman endpoint seems to be sending the same data, after loading the `/getCsrfToken` endpoint and I manually update the `_csrf` token.

[image: postman example]

Is there something I'm not doing correctly? I think it may be to do with Node.js's cookie system.

Comment: hey did you find any solution yet @luke

Comment: Unfortunately not @gaurav, we ended up moving away from _csrf approach since nobody in my team could get it working. We just built our own simple CSRF check using a custom express middleware function and recording of tokens either in node-cache or db

Comment: Thanks @luke we are facing a similar kind of scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is likely to be related to CORS (your dev tools will probably have sent a warning?).

Here's the simplest working back-end and front-end I could make, based on the documentation:

## In Back-End (NodeJS with Express) Server:

### In app.js:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');

var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

var app = express()

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.json({ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
})

module.exports = app;
```

(make sure you update the `corsOptions` `origin` property to whatever your localhost is in React.

### In Index.js:

```js
const app = require('./app')

app.set('port', 5000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('App running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

## In React:

### Create file "TestCsurf.js" and populate with this code:

```
    import React from 'react'
    
    export default function TestCsurf() {
    
        let domainUrl = `http://localhost:5000`
        const [csrfTokenState, setCsrfTokenState] = React.useState('')
        const [haveWeReceivedPostResponseState, setHaveWeReceivedPostResponseState] = React.useState("Not yet. No data has been processed.")
    
        async function getCallToForm() {
            const url = `/form`;
            let fetchGetResponse = await fetch(`${domainUrl}${url}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "xsrf-token": localStorage.getItem('xsrf-token'),
                },
                credentials: "include",
                mode: 'cors'
            })
            let parsedResponse = await fetchGetResponse.json();
            setCsrfTokenState(parsedResponse.csrfToken)
        }
    
        React.useEffect(() => {
            getCallToForm()
        }, [])
    
        async function testCsurfClicked() {
            const url = `/process`
            let fetchPostResponse = await fetch(`${domainUrl}${url}`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "xsrf-token": csrfTokenState,
                },
                credentials: "include",
                mode: 'cors',
            })
            let parsedResponse = await fetchPostResponse.text()
            setHaveWeReceivedPostResponseState(parsedResponse)
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={testCsurfClicked}>Test Csurf Post Call</button>
                <p>csrfTokenState is: {csrfTokenState}</p>
                <p>Have we succesfully navigates csurf with token?: {JSON.stringify(haveWeReceivedPostResponseState)}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

### Import this into your app.js

```js
import CsurfTutorial from './CsurfTutorial';

function App() {
  return (
    <CsurfTutorial></CsurfTutorial>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That's the simplest solution I can make based on the CSURF documentations example. It's taken me several days to figure this out. I wish they'd give us a bit more direction!

I made a tutorial video in case it's of any help to anyone: https://youtu.be/N5U7KtxvVto

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.
the only difference is I'm using Vue and expecting the token in the request headers. and that I've already handled cors errors. the `csrfProtection` won't work if I'm sending the token from vue 3 $fetch composable. PS: I can log the token its being sent properly from the front-end. i think it might be a bug since the package is deprecated